# Not in [array] vue js

Tags: vue.js, validation

I want validate a field with vue js validations that can not be in specific values 
exemple : `array = ['apple','banana']` 
I want that `fruit` data can't be in `array`

any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with Vue

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let array1 = ['apple','banana'];
let array2 = ['apple','orange'];
let fruit = 'banana';

let isValid1 = !array1.includes(fruit);
let isValid2 = !array2.includes(fruit);

console.log(isValid1);   // false
console.log(isValid2);   // true
```

Here is a bit more on `includes` works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: yeh it's a solution to check before submit, but i think that there is a rule in vues js like `not in` to simplify the ocde, but it seems no